# Sum of 3 different values separately MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have tweet list, which contains three fields, tweet id, topicIdTag and type. type has three different values. I'm getting the result but further I want to get a count of each type. My model and query code is as follows.

```
model : {
        TopicIdTag : String,
        TweetId : String,
        type :String //Positive,negative,neutral
    },

 db.collection("myTweets").aggregate( [
                                  {
                                    $group: {
                                       _id: {
                                            TopicIdTag : "$TopicIdTag",
                                            TweetId : "$TweetId",
                                       },
                                       count: { $sum: 1 }
                                    }
                                  },
                                   { $match: { count: { $gt: 0  , $lt : 5  } } },
                                // Then sort
                                   { "$sort": { "count": -1 } }
                               ], (err, result) => {
                                   if (err) {
                                       console.log(err);
                                   }
                                   res.status(200).send(result);
                               } );

        });
```

this query give me total number tweets group by id. the query should also return how many time type was positive, negative, and neutral in a specific tweet Id.

Comment: adding type in the $group stage should give you a count of each type but to be honest I don't think I uderstand what's going on, why whould you group by TweetId? Isn't TweetId unique?

Comment: one tweetID have multiple entries. there are some other entries which i skipped here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the existing `$group` to include `type` and count by `type` and add another group with `$addtoSet` to add one entry per each `type` and `count`  and total count by  `TopicIdTag` & `TweetId`.

```
db.collection("tweets").aggregate([{
  $group: {
      _id: {
          Time: "$Time",
          TopicIdTag: "$TopicIdTag",
          TweetId: "$TweetId",
          TweetText: "$TweetText",
          UserName: "$UserName",
          UserScreenname: "$UserScreenname",
          sentimentNumber: "$sentimentNumber",
          setimentText: "$setimentText",
          //user feed back type
          type: "$type"
      },
      count: {
          $sum: 1
      }
  }
}, {
  $group: {
      _id: {
          Time: "$_id.Time",
          TopicIdTag: "$_id.TopicIdTag",
          TweetId: "$_id.TweetId",
          TweetText: "$_id.TweetText",
          UserName: "$_id.UserName",
          UserScreenname: "$_id.UserScreenname",
          sentimentNumber: "$_id.sentimentNumber",
          setimentText: "$_id.setimentText"
      },
      typeAndCount: {
          $addToSet: {
              type: "$_id.type",
              count: "$count"
          }
      },
      totalCount: {
          $sum: 1
      }
  }
}, {
  $match: {
      totalCount: {
          $gt: 0,
          $lt: 5
      }
  }
}])
```

Comment: I am getting the empty string. I thing i'm doing some thing wronge. I Have updated my query .. please check it.

Comment: Updated answer. You missed the `_id` reference in the last group. See if it works.

Comment: Your query works perfect. one thing still totalCount is giving total number of type not the actual count of main group. how i can get that one for exame count should be 24, if  (type1 = 11, type2= 15)

Comment: I don't have data to validate but query looks okay to me.